# Need to delete the previous row in a Excel sheet based on a cell value in a current cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing my first macro for this project that has the following data exports from a motion sensor. It has a 'No Motion' after every 'Motion Detected' row. This 'No Motion' is a  glitch within that sensor's firmware that I cannot edit. So it looks like this:

```
DataMessageGUID SensorID    Sensor Name Date    Value   Formatted Value Battery
5d6f57c1-7449-4da3-a9fa-9709ae4b0671    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:57   0   No Motion   100
adaa026e-8847-4eab-ac48-6ac93fc93f16    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:56   1   Motion Detected 100
0b4287f2-258e-48d5-97e6-e00ed3c68a6a    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:56   0   No Motion   100
0a3ba320-f8e5-4ae9-97ac-26c5269e811e    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:55   1   Motion Detected 100
1946aa41-fbaf-4a0d-8e5e-c846ef0cdb24    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:55   0   No Motion   100
ae214e59-c93f-4832-bfd9-5c011a60435a    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:54   1   Motion Detected 100
c2518ff0-053c-49fd-99e6-e6ed20798279    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:22   0   No Motion   100
e1678d9e-c919-4378-8021-cc669b45918a    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:21   1   Motion Detected 100
ed8c20ee-3630-4b68-8063-788b25f7c433    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:19   0   No Motion   100
7d537313-9133-4525-9ef8-fcb1fbce81ad    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:19   1   Motion Detected 100
dcaa463c-0ff0-4a17-9881-f67641fae014    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:16   0   No Motion   100
c66d16d2-063b-4aca-bd81-3abdaaa3063f    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:15   1   Motion Detected 100
1fbf6e16-c8e8-4a18-ae71-42195fcf6e48    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:14   0   No Motion   100
7f5ed16c-ab3d-411e-a2c7-851eeb5641d4    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:13   1   Motion Detected 100
63f79047-143b-4b17-a359-6d6eac1d3a43    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:13   0   No Motion   100
52f857f2-5b5b-4fec-b7da-67390236f473    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:12   1   Motion Detected 100
19bce92e-0068-4f46-ac1d-a79877c88a0c    301232  Bedroom Left    8/4/2017 8:12   0   No Motion   100
```

I need to remove the 'No Motion that shows up immediately after the 'Motion Detected' rows.

With the help of a code online I edited, I got this:

```
Sub Macro_Delete_rows()
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow    As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "F")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "Motion Detected" Then .Rows(Lrow - 1).EntireRow.Delete
                'Here I try to delete previous row to this row
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

This doesn't really work and mostly I end up deleting the wrong rows. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your `For` loop:

```
  For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "F")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "No Motion" And .Offset(-1, 0) = "Motion Detected" Then
                    .EntireRow.Select
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
```

The idea is that it looks to see if the current row is "No Motion" **and** the previous row is "Motion Detected". If so, delete that "No Motion" row.

Your original code was on the right track, but notice it wouldn't delete that last "No Motion" line, since there's no "Motion Detected" row after it.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem.

```
Sub Macro_Delete_rows()
Dim TotalRows As Long
TotalRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("yourSheetName").Range("A:A"))
    For i = 2 To TotalRows
        'You can delete the data by 0 before No Moton Cell

        'if G colomn has No Motion
        Range("G" & i).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = "No Motion" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
            i = 1 - 1
        End If
'        'If F column has 0
'        Range("F" & i).Select
'        If ActiveCell.Value = 0 Then
'            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
'            i = 1 - 1
'        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```